# MongoCursor Implementation

Tags: objective-c, mongodb, objcmongodb

I’m using Paulmelnikow’s ObjCMongoDB to connect to a mongodb in my iOS. I want to load the data in chunks using MongoCursor. I need help to implement this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can just invoke `-[MongoDBCollection cursorForFindAllWithError:]`, or one of the other methods which returns a cursor, and then iterate over it.

```
NSError *error = nil;

MongoCursor *cursor = [collection cursorForFindAllWithError:&error];

if (cursor) {
    for (BSONDocument *document in cursor) {
        // do something with document
    }
} else {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```